# Разблокировка по лицу или FaceId

Tags: android

Используя BiometricPrompt запускаю авторизацию по биометрии.

```
val executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext())
val biometricPrompt =
    BiometricPrompt(requireActivity(), executor, object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
        override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
        }

        override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
        }
    })

val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
    .setTitle(getString(R.string.login))
    .setSubtitle("test")
    .setNegativeButtonText(getString(R.string.cancel))
    .build()

biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
```

Но при этом есть возможность только авторизации по отпечатку пальца. В настройках андроида включил "Разблокировку по лицу", но эффекта это не дало. Пробовал отключить отпечаток пальца, но при этом все еще выходит диалог с авторизацией по отпечатку пальца.

Я так понимаю, у меня устройство с неполноценным FaceId?

Пробовал на устройствах:

- Poco M3 pro
- Xiaomi MI A3

Build тестового приложения с идентичным кодом и dependencies https://dropmefiles.com/wufqF

Comment: Скинь билд, протещу

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: У меня только отпечаток пальца выходит

Comment: Спасибо за тест! А у вас какое устройство? Прочитал в форумах о том, что многие производителе добавляют свой аналог faceId и он не имеет ничего общего с авторизацией по биометрии через библиотеку androidx.biometric:biometric, это так или я чего-то недополнял?)

Comment: У меня Xiaomi mi 9t pro, на счёт биометрики не совсем уверен, но врятли, разве что только в miui они что нибудь начудить могут

Comment: Ты можешь скачать bluestacks/nox на пк и уже туда поставить чистый андроид или какие-нибудь оболочку

Comment: Судя вот по таким ответам, из коробки не все устройства поддерживаются https://stackoverflow.com/a/69513669/3671076